# Error when performing terraform plan after upgrading terraform to v0.11.7, use splat syntax to access defined attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

after upgrading my terraform, my naming module broke, and i'm not sure how to fix the naming module.

```js
data "aws_region" "current" {
  current = true
}
 
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  count = "${var.has_vpc_id == 0 ? 0 : 1}"
  id    = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
 
output "iam" {
  value = "${
      join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
        )),
        var.friendly_name
      ))}"
}
 
output "vpc" {
  value = "${
    map(
      "none", join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
        )),
        element(split("-", lookup(data.aws_vpc.vpc.*.tags, "Name")), var.vpc-name-offset),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      )),
      "a", join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
          "a"
        )),
        element(split("-", lookup(data.aws_vpc.vpc.*.tags, "Name")), var.vpc-name-offset),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      )),
      "b", join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
          "b"
        )),
        element(split("-", lookup(data.aws_vpc.vpc.*.tags, "Name")), var.vpc-name-offset),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      )),
      "c", join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
          "c"
        )),
        element(split("-", lookup(data.aws_vpc.vpc.*.tags, "Name")), var.vpc-name-offset),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      )),
      "d", join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
          "d"
        )),
        element(split("-", lookup(data.aws_vpc.vpc.*.tags, "Name")), var.vpc-name-offset),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      ))
    )
  }"
}
 
output "no_vpc" {
  value = "${
      join("-", list(
        join("", list(
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 0), 0, 2),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 1), 0, 1),
          substr(element(split("-", data.aws_region.current.name), 2), 0, 1),
        )),
        lookup(var.environments, var.environment),
        var.friendly_name
      ))}"
}
```

error that i'm getting is as follows:
warning: output "vpc": must use splat syntax to access data.aws_vpc.vpc attribute "tags", becuase it has "count" set; use data.aws_vpc.*.tags to obtain a list of the attributes across all instances